# Setting same specific width to columns of sequential tables produces horizontal offset

Tags: tables, longtable

I obtain weird results when I sequentially arrange several tables with specific column widths

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs, array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}


\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{R{139.4185pt} L{278.837pt}} %Numbers are .3333 and .6666 of \textwidth
    Bla & Bla\\
\end{longtable}

\begin{tabular}{R{139.4185pt} L{278.837pt}}
    Bla & Bla\\
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{R{139.4185pt} L{278.837pt}}
    Bla & Bla\\
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{R{139.4185pt} L{278.837pt}}
    Bla & Bla\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

This produces unwanted offset that sometimes depends on whether there is an empty line before a `tabular` or not. No matter where I place the longtable, the next tabular has wrong offset:

[image: Example of wrong offsets]

What's going on?

Comment: Add `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}` To your preamble. What is happening is that each table is being placed like a paragraph hence satisfying the indentation of the document.

Comment: Isn't this somewhat counterintuitive as a default behaviour for tables?

Comment: @BandGap `tablular` are _inline_ constructs they are positioned like a letter `A` If you put two in the source file they come side by side if you put one at the start of a paragraph it is indented by the paragraph indent. If you want to make a vertical display out of a table normally you need something like `begin{center}\begin{tabular}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The effect is as a result of the default indentation of the document. Place `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}` in the preamble if you want zero indentation or `\noindent` before each table to remove the indentation and the effect will be removed.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs, array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{R{139.4185pt} L{278.837pt}} %Numbers are .3333 and .6666 of \textwidth
    Bla & Bla\\
\end{longtable}

\begin{tabular}{R{139.4185pt} L{278.837pt}}
    Bla & Bla\\
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{R{139.4185pt} L{278.837pt}}
    Bla & Bla\\
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{R{139.4185pt} L{278.837pt}}
    Bla & Bla\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent, it works. I had the impression it would be easy to solve... Thanks